# How do I do updates for my laravel project?

Tags: laravel, command-line, terminal, updates

What command can I use to see a list of all my installed packages and do the update ? (through the terminal)

Comment: view  composer.json file in root directory. composer install to install packages and composer update to update packages

Comment: Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37804187/3585500) if you want to update just one package (that might have other dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

If you have composer run in the console

```
composer show --installed
```

For updating all your dependencies run in the console

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

To show installed packages run: **`composer show --installed`**

To update installed packages run: **`composer update`**

And Read these  documents [this](https://composer.json.jolicode.com/) and [this](https://devhints.io/composer)